# Django: How do I load models dynamically in app scripts

Tags: django

I have a script called `helpers.py` in my Django app in which I can't import models because it creates a circular reference.

As a workaround to this problem, I tried loading the modules dynamically in the script, like so:

```
from django.apps import apps

MyModel=apps.get_model("mymodule", "MyModel")
```

but this gets called before Django loads models and throws an error.

Is there a way around this problem?

Ideally I need to be able to create references to the model after Django has initialised the models, so that its available throughout the script, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: If it could load it you wouldn't have a circular reference in the first place. Did you try local imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need models inside your `helpers.py`? If needed stuff is related to a model consider implementing this as a model method or a custom manager.

If you are sure you need models in your `helpers.py`, then look at the examples below.

---

As @Selcuk mentioned you can try a local import in a function of the `helpers.py`. This example **works** even if `helpers.py` is imported in the `models.py`:

```
# helpers.py

def foo():
    from .models import MyModel
    # do something with MyModel
```

---

On the top of your `helpers.py` which has a circular import of the `models.py` you can import the whole `models` module without specifying the names you want to import from it. So the next example **works** too:

```
# helpers.py
import myapp.models

def foo():
    # do something with myapp.models.MyModel
```

---

But the next **doesn't work**, because we specify the name from the module (that may be not defined yet):

```
# helpers.py
from .models import MyModel
# ImportError is risen when you import a name from the module which has a circular import of this module

def foo():
    # do something with MyModel
```

---

And this **doesn't work** too. It will import the module, but when you try to access the name MyModel you will get NameError:

```
# helpers.py
from .models import *

def foo():
    # do something with MyModel
    # NameError is risen when you do something with MyModel here
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need the model in helpers.py and I need helpers in models. Reason: there are some convenience functions which get called in the `save` override in the model, which are in helpers, and the helpers requires to model to do its work. There are other dependencies because of which I can't change this structure.

Comment: @Bitonator then try one of the working examples in the second part of my answer (do a local import or import the whole module). Please tell me if it doesn't work in your case, I will try to help.

Comment: Thanks much Max! local imports saved the day. Just realised that its not too bad of a performance hit on a running server either. Probably only the first call to a local import may take time to process.

Comment: @Bitonator Correct, imported module is executed only on the first import.  All subsequent imports will return a reference to already imported and executed module.